# In Groovy 3, about 80 new such extension methods were added. Where I can find the complete list?

Tags: groovy

According to [Groovy 3.0 release notes](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#Groovy3.0releasenotes-GDKimprovements):

> Groovy adds many extension methods to existing Java classes. In Groovy
> 3, about 80 new such extension methods were added. We highlight just a
> few here: ...

I need the complete list of such new methods that didn't exists in 2.5.x branch. Where I can find it (Google is not helping me :/ )?

**Motivation**: I developed a [groovy extension library](https://gitlab.com/intellisrc/groovy-extend) with methods that I often use which Groovy doesn't have. I'm about to update it to use Groovy 3.0.3, but I would like to remove any method that is already implemented in Groovy.

As this question was closed, I will answer it here for those interested:

### Answer:

I received help in the groovy mailing list:

> If you have the source code and an IDE and search for '@since 3.0' you will find 79 results when searching with *Methods.java as the file mask and 1 with *Extensions.java as the file mask. There might be some that were added without @since or in files that match some other file mask but that's a good start.

This is what I found:

#### Default Groovy Methods:

```java
void printf(Closure self, String format, Object[] values)
void printf(Closure self, String format, Object value)
Object average(Iterable self)
Object average(Object[] self)
Object average(Iterator<Object> self)
BigDecimal average(byte[] self) 
BigDecimal average(short[] self)
BigDecimal average(int[] self)
BigDecimal average(long[] self) 
double average(float[] self)
double average(double[] self)
<T> Object average(Iterable<T> self, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.FirstGenericType.class) Closure closure)
<T> Object average(T[] self, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.Component.class) Closure closure)
<T> Object average(Iterator<T> self, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.FirstGenericType.class) Closure closure)
void shuffle(List<?> self)
void shuffle(List<?> self, Random rnd)
<T> List<T> shuffled(List<T> self)
<T> List<T> shuffled(List<T> self, Random rnd)
<T> void shuffle(T[] self)
<T> void shuffle(T[] self, Random rnd)
<T> T[] shuffled(T[] self)
<T> T[] shuffled(T[] self, Random rnd)
Boolean isAtLeast(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right)
Boolean isAtLeast(BigDecimal left, String right)
```

#### String

```java
Boolean isAtLeast(String left, String right) 
CharSequence takeRight(CharSequence self, int num)
String takeRight(String self, int num)
String takeRight(GString self, int num)
CharSequence takeAfter(CharSequence self, CharSequence searchString)
String takeAfter(String self, CharSequence searchString)
String takeAfter(GString self, CharSequence searchString)
CharSequence takeBefore(CharSequence self, CharSequence searchString)
String takeBefore(GString self, String searchString)
String takeBefore(String self, String searchString)
CharSequence dropRight(CharSequence self, int num)
String dropRight(String self, int num)
String dropRight(GString self, int num)
CharSequence takeBetween(CharSequence self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to)
String takeBetween(String self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to)
String takeBetween(GString self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to)
CharSequence takeBetween(CharSequence self, CharSequence enclosure)
String takeBetween(String self, CharSequence enclosure)
String takeBetween(GString self, CharSequence enclosure)
CharSequence takeBetween(CharSequence self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to, int occurrence) 
String takeBetween(String self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to, int occurrence) 
String takeBetween(GString self, CharSequence from, CharSequence to, int occurrence) 
CharSequence takeBetween(CharSequence self, CharSequence enclosure, int occurrence)
String takeBetween(String self, CharSequence enclosure, int occurrence)
String takeBetween(GString self, CharSequence enclosure, int occurrence)
boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(CharSequence self, CharSequence searchString)
boolean endsWithIgnoreCase(CharSequence self, CharSequence searchString)
boolean containsIgnoreCase(CharSequence self, CharSequence searchString)
static dumpAll(Thread self)
```

#### Java8 extensions:

```java
int get(final OptionalInt self)
long get(final OptionalLong self)
double get(final OptionalDouble self) 
<T> Optional<T> filter(final Optional<?> self, final Class<T> type)
OptionalInt filter(final OptionalInt self, final IntPredicate test) 
OptionalLong filter(final OptionalLong self, final LongPredicate test)
OptionalDouble filter(final OptionalDouble self, final DoublePredicate test)
<T> Optional<T> mapToObj(final OptionalInt self, final IntFunction<? extends T> mapper)
<T> Optional<T> mapToObj(final OptionalLong self, final LongFunction<? extends T> mapper)
<T> Optional<T> mapToObj(final OptionalDouble self, final DoubleFunction<? extends T> mapper)
<T> OptionalInt mapToInt(final Optional<T> self, final ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)
<T> OptionalLong mapToLong(final Optional<T> self, final ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper)
<T> OptionalDouble mapToDouble(final Optional<T> self, final ToDoubleFunction<? super T> mapper)
<S,T> Optional<T> collect(final Optional<S> self, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.FirstGenericType.class) final Closure<T> transform)
<S,T> Future<T> collect(final Future<S> self, @ClosureParams(FirstParam.FirstGenericType.class) final Closure<T> transform)
<T> Stream<T> stream(final NullObject self)
<T> Stream<T> stream(final T self) 
<T> Stream<T> stream(final Enumeration<T> self)
<T> Stream<T> stream(final Iterable<T> self) 
<T> Stream<T> stream(final Iterator<T> self) 
<T> Stream<T> stream(final Spliterator<T> self)
<T> Stream<T> stream(final Optional<T> self) 
IntStream stream(final OptionalInt self) 
LongStream stream(final OptionalLong self)
DoubleStream stream(final OptionalDouble self)
```